# Android - как дождаться окончания анимации?

Tags: android, android-animation

Как сделать так, чтобы код следующий после использования анимации, дождался завершения анимации? Сейчас он начинает выполняться параллельно с запуском анимации.

**Метод в котором используется анимация:**

```
private void moveToHistory() {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.move_operation);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                historyField.setText(getNumberField());
                historyOperation.setText(operationField.getText().toString());
                numberField.setText(" ");
                operationField.setText(" ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });

        numberField.startAnimation(animation);
        operationField.startAnimation(animation);
    }
```

**Еще один метод с анимацией:**

```
private void clearCalculation() {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.dissolution);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                numberField.setText(" ");
                operationField.setText(" ");
                historyField.setText(" ");
                historyOperation.setText(" ");

                isPercentCalculation = false;
                isResult = false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });

        numberField.startAnimation(animation);
        operationField.startAnimation(animation);
        historyField.startAnimation(animation);
        historyOperation.startAnimation(animation);
    }
```

**Пример кода в котором могут вызываться методы с анимацией:**

```
private void addNumber(String s) {
        if (isResult || isError()) clearCalculation(); //есть анимация
        if (!isEmpty(operationField)) moveToHistory(); //есть анимация

        //вот эта часть начинает выполняться сразу после запуска анимации
        //не дожидаясь результата работы onAnimationEnd()
        if (getCountNumbers(numberField) < 11) {
            if (getNumberField().equals("0")) {
                String temp = "0." + s;
                numberField.setText(temp);
            } else {
                String temp = getNumberField() + s;
                numberField.setText(temp);
            }
        }
    }
```

Методы с анимацией вызываются во многих местах программы. Часто после вызова этих методов следует другой код, который начинает выполняться до завершения анимации. А мне нужно чтобы он подождал, потому что в блоках onAnimationEnd() выполняется то, что должно быть завершено до выполнения дальнейшего кода.

Перемещение всего кода в блок onAnimationEnd() не является решением.

Comment: Вот здесь - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321344/android-animation-wait-until-finished нашел что-то похожее на решение. Создать объект для инкапсуляции времени жизни анимации. Но не хватает знаний и английского, чтобы разобраться как это использовать. Может кто-нибудь помочь?

Answer (score 2):

**UPD:** Чтож, давайте разбираться в причинах того, что у Вас происходит:

Сразу же после старта анимации Вы вызываете блок кода:

```
//вот эта часть начинает выполняться сразу после запуска анимации
//не дожидаясь результата работы onAnimationEnd()
if (getCountNumbers(numberField) < 11) {
    if (getNumberField().equals("0")) {
        String temp = "0." + s;
        numberField.setText(temp);
    } else {
        String temp = getNumberField() + s;
        numberField.setText(temp);
    }
}
```

В документации пишут, что анимация выполняется в том же потоке, в котором она была вызвана. Так почему же Ваш блок кода выполняется во время анимации, если поток один и тот же?

Дело в том, что исполнение анимации бьётся на "программные кадры", выполнение которых передаётся в `Looper` UI-потока (далее - Главный поток). Каждый кадр анимации вызывается в Главном потоке последовательно, но не обязательно непрерывно друг за другом. Разная анимация нескольких `View`-элементов происходит как бы одновременно, потому что такие кадры смешиваются и последовательно выполняется по кадру от каждой анимации.

Ваш блок кода тоже выполняется в главном потоке. Скорее всего даже раньше выполнения первого кадра анимации, потому что Ваш блок на тот момент уже находится в `Looper`-е главного потока, в то время, когда первый кадр анимации только что был сформирован и запланирован.

Ну а теперь, что касается выполнения Вашего блока в конце анимации. Вы можете гарантированно выполнить Ваш блок кода в конце анимации, выполнив его в методе `onAnimationEnd` Вашего `Listener`-a.

Сложность возникает только из-за того, что у Вас 2 анимации на 6 `View`-полей. А стало быть в одном методе, где у Вас 4 вызова анимации будет 4 раза вызван `onAnimationEnd`, в другом методе 2 раза.

Вам необходимо Ваш финальный блок кода вынести в отдельный метод, например `finalMethod()` - название и сигнатуру определите для себя самостоятельно.   Затем определить, конец последней анимации, например добавив счетчик.

Пример для одного из методов:

```
int mAnimationCount;

private void clearCalculation() {
    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.dissolution);
    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            numberField.setText(" ");
            operationField.setText(" ");
            historyField.setText(" ");
            historyOperation.setText(" ");

            isPercentCalculation = false;
            isResult = false;

            if (--mAnimationCount == 0) {
                finalMethod();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        }
    });

    numberField.startAnimation(animation);
    operationField.startAnimation(animation);
    historyField.startAnimation(animation);
    historyOperation.startAnimation(animation);

    mAnimationCount = 4; // количество запущенных Вами анимаций
}
```

Это только пример, не знаю особенностей Вашего кода, потому подберите себе наиболее удобный способ определения.

**UPD 2:** Не могу представить примера и причины, почему нельзя воспользоваться правильным путём, разве что лень разрешать конфликты вытекающие из одновременного вызова метода `onAnimationEnd` у анимаций. Но если уж совсем лень, то можно финальные блоки кода передавать в очередь исполнения, пример для Вашего вопроса из комментариев, как отложить старт кода на 200мс:

```
private void addNumber(String s) {
    if (isResult || isError()) clearCalculation(); //есть анимация
    if (!isEmpty(operationField)) moveToHistory(); //есть анимация

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (getCountNumbers(numberField) < 11) {
                if (getNumberField().equals("0")) {
                    String temp = "0." + s;
                    numberField.setText(temp);
                } else {
                    String temp = getNumberField() + s;
                    numberField.setText(temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }, 200); // время задержки в миллисекундах
```

Конечно такой вариант менее правильный в случае, если последовательность окончания анимации и вашего блока кода важна, а также если недопустима большая задержка между последовательностью этих событий.

Не забывайте, что `Handler` не обязательно создавать самому, можно воспользоваться им через ближайшую `View`, например `mTextView.postDelayed(...)`.

Вариант с созданием параллельного потока кажется излишним и понесёт за собой больше проблем, чем попытаться разрешить вероятные конфликты в методе `onAnimationEnd`.

Comment: Этот код работает только вне контекста другого кода. А если выполняется много кода, внутри которого например вызывается метод очистки полей, в котором реализована анимация этой очистки, то можно конечно что-то выполнить при завершении анимации, но проблема остается. Код, который выполняется "после", начинает выполняться уже в процессе анимации, что только усугубляет ситуацию, потому что поля, которые должны быть очищены перед выполнением кода, по факту будут очищены только при завершении анимации.

Comment: Зачем так много слов, так много текста :) По факту у Вас одна анимация на два TextView. Ничего не понял, но мб Ваша проблема из-за этого?) У Вас должно приходить два раза End, определяйте для какого TextView оно пришло.

Comment: Я не писал, что у меня в программе только одна анимация и два поля, это лишь пример. И работа программы не заканчивается выполнением метода onAnimationEnd(). Прочтите внимательно мое **дополнение** к вопросу.

Comment: Обновил ответ - та же мысль, но более подробно :)

Comment: Вы опять все свели к выполнению блока onAnimationEnd(). Давайте представим, что там ничего нет и не нужно считать количество запущенных анимаций, потому что это никак не влияет на суть проблемы. После анимации **в любом случае идет другой код**, который всегда исполняться одновременно с анимацией. Как мне притормозить его исполнение? Например на 200ms. Пробовал использовать альтернативную нить с задержкой и отложенный старт, но это либо не срабатывает, либо зависает (в разных вариантах исполнения).

Comment: Блок кода следующий после анимации нельзя вынести в отдельный метод и всегда запускать в методе onAnimationEnd(). Потому что метод с анимацией вызывается в десятке различных мест и код следующий за ним всегда разный.

Comment: Обновил ответ, добавил менее правильный вариант, но если уж захочется, то может сгодиться.

Comment: Зачем даете ответ с кодом отложенного старта после комментария, в котором я говорю, что в данной ситуации он не работает? В UI потоке он все подвесит на указанное время, а после - анимация и отложенный код будут запущены одновременно.

Comment: @kulikovman Вы упорно не хотите применять правильный ответ к своей ситуации, а тормозом называете меня? Ввиду того, что Вы говорите какими-то загадками типа - "В моей ситуации это не работает, потому что много кода..." и упорно на это давите, сложно решить Вашу проблему за Вас и адаптировать Ваш код под правильное решение. Я показывал Вам пример на Ваш же вопрос из комментария "Как притормозить исполнение кода на 200мс", в примере сначала стартует анимация, потом через 200 мс выполнение финального кода. Если у Вас тяжелая задача, то выполняйте финальный метод в фоновом потоке. В чем проблема?

Comment: @kulikovman Вы говорите - "мне надо, чтобы сначала выполнялась анимация, потом она закончилась, потом выполнился какой-то код, потом выполнился мой код". Я Вам расписал как это последовательно сделать. Дальше я уже начал гадать, по комментарием, что же Вам на самом деле надо. Может дело не в ответе, а в неправильно сформулированном вопросе? Перечитайте его с позиции людей, которые не знакомы с Вашим проектом.